# How to get the top level parent term related to the current archive page?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy called `product_category` that holds products. How does one get the top-level parent term with a list of children terms?

I know how to get a global list of top-level terms using `get_terms()` and passing in `'0'` as the parent, but I only want the one that it related to the current archive page.

Example:

**Magazines**
--Glossy
----Fashion
**Books**
--Hardcover
----Adventure

If I happened to be on the Fashion archive, I only want to get *Magazines* with a list of child terms, not *Books*.

Answer (score 6):

I think I figured it out. I ended up with the following:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id; //Get ID of current term
$ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'product_category' ); // Get a list of ancestors
$ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors); //Reverse the array to put the top level ancestor first
$ancestors[0] ? $top_term_id = $ancestors[0] : $top_term_id = $term_id; //Check if there is an ancestor, else use id of current term
$term = get_term( $top_term_id, 'product_category' ); //Get the term
echo $term->name; // Echo name of top level ancestor
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this, but this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I like that solution cbi. I can't believe I've had such a difficulty getting this information when making a custom hierarchical taxonomy term archive.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'categories' );
  if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
    // get the first term
    $term = array_shift( $terms );
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
  }

  $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'categories' ); // Get a list of ancestors
  $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors); //Reverse the array to put the top level ancestor first
  $ancestors[0] ? $top_term_id = $ancestors[0] : $top_term_id = $term_id; //Check if there is an ancestor, else use id of current term
  $term = get_term( $top_term_id, 'categories' ); //Get the term
  $top_term_id = $term->term_id;
  echo $top_term_id; // Echo name of top level ancestor

?>
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.